# get spreadsheet URL

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a problem in my reporting, i create every day a google doc tracker where all the stack holders in my department update their work progress in it, so i have plenty of spreadsheets to monitor which is a hassle, here is what im trying to do, I'm trying to create a big google doc tracker where i can have an access over date applied in the normal spreadsheets, all what i need is the spreadsheet's URLs that exist in my google drive to be retrieved in this big tracker, with this i'll be able to drive all the needed data from the normal trackers.

PS: I'm not good with google scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) to get a list of files with MIME type "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" using [getFilesByType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByType(String)). This returns a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), which you can use to individually get each Spreadsheet file. From there, just use [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl()) to find the URL's. The FileIterator link has examples of how to loop through all the matching files.